# Is there usleep for Ubuntu?

Tags: sleep, nano

There's `usleep()` in `libc`, but I didn't find any command line utility to do this.

Though I've written a piece of C code, I'm still wonder if it already existed somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SleepEnh](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/sleepenh) maybe?

Comment: Well, sleepenh uses float numbers, I'm just curious whether it's useable in embedded system. Thanks.

Comment: The link doesn't work. This is the issue with link only answers

Answer (score 1):

There is a version of usleep as part of the nosql RDBM package.  The installation of nosql requires procmail and postfix, so it is a bit heavy handed to install all that for one tiny utility.

However, if you locate and download the .deb package without installing it, you can use tar to unwind it (a deb package is simply a compressed tar file containing compressed tar files).  Extract only `/usr/lib/nosql/usleep`, and put it somewhere in your path where you have permissions to install it (`/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, `~/bin)`.  It "just worked" on my Lucid system, so apparently the required libraries (glibc I'd bet) are there; no additional packages required.

Answer (score 1):

Install the busybox package, it includes usleep.

Comment: This didn't seem to help, as usleep still was not found.

Answer (score 1):

"sleep" program in gnu coreutil, can take decimal numbers.

```
sleep 0.2
```

Anyway, sleep will not be accurate because of starting delay to launch the program.